# Unable to reset windows 11 laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-11

Recently I was trying to reset my razer blade (15 I believe) because I want to sell it. So I went into settings and went on the recovery page and followed the instructions. After that it restarted and I am now on the recovery page. When I now try to go to troubleshot and then go to reset your pc and then click on remove everything and cloud download it will give me the error “there was a problem resetting your pc“ every other combination reset your pc does not work for example local reinstall also has the same code and even keep files does not work although the cloud version there just tells me I have no connection and to use local reinstall however that again does not work. I have searched this up and it seems to be a common error however all the fixes seem to involve doing something on in settings but I already completely deleted everything in the first step which now prevents me from using windows 11 and any of my old files. Can anyone help me with this? Or do I just need to buy a new windows 11 usb stick?

Comment: Do you have a spare laptop/pc and a blank USB stick? You can make a Windows boot disk yourself

Comment: Any website that requires you pay for a Windows 11 ISO is a scam.  The only thing that requires a payment is for a Windows 11 license.  Your machine presumable came with either Windows 10 or Windows 11.  So you absolutely DO NOT need to purchase a Windows 11 license in order to install it.  The solution to your problem is simple, create a Windows 11 installation media, delete all partitions on your system and then install Windows 11 to the unallocated partition that has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I totally agree @Ramhound. You don't have to buy Windows 11 USB stick because you can easily create it by your own. Also, if Reset PC option is not working properly then it better format your computer by reinstalling the operating system. This will remove all your data and cached files that has been used.

Hope it helps :)